# Setup auto deployment for laravel app from bitbucket to heroku

Tags: heroku, bitbucket, bitbucket-pipelines

I'm trying to setup bitbucket pipeline to auto deploy laravel app to heroku 
 1. Created an app on heroku
 2. pushed the code to bitbucket repo
 3. added repo environment on bitbucket with the name of the heroku app and app key 
 4. created .yml file and put this code http://prntscr.com/rb3u4p
 5. Pipeline fails http://prntscr.com/rb3ybo

It says the zip file name i mentioned on the yml not found, do i need to create the zip on Heroku. I already created the same zip file on my local and pushed to bitbucket.

Answer (score 0):

You have to zip the source code of you application in your pipelines so the pipe can push in to Heroku. This guide provides a good example https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucket/deploy-to-heroku-872013667.html